# Is there a way to count values from a year prior (YoY%)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently using mySQL and really struggling to figure this seemingly-simple query out. I'm trying to track registrations by month, with a year over year comparison that selects the # of registrations from a given date, the # of registrations from that same date but a year prior, and then an additional column that takes the percent change between the two.

I  have the following columns so far with no problem:

```
Date | User Registrations
__________
```

However, I am trying to get:

```
Date | User Registrations | Previous Year # | % Change
_______
```

This is my current query.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') AS "Month", count(*) AS "New User Registrations", 
from users
WHERE `created_at` > "2018-01-01 00:00:00"
INNER JOIN
GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at)
```

---

If anyone has any idea of how to grab the matching values from one year prior, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data for every month, use `lag()`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M %Y') AS "Month",
       COUNT(*) AS "New User Registrations", 
       LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(created_at)) as prev_year,
       ( COUNT(*) / LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(created_at)) ) - 1 as change
FROM users u
WHERE `created_at` > '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%M %Y')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! Unfortunately it's not working. I do have information/data in every month though. Is there something else I should be looked out for?]